# Reading Inputs in Java - help

Tags: java, input

I am having a problem reading inputs, can anyone help me.

Each line of the input have to Integers: X e Y separated by a space.

```
12 1    
12 3  
23 4  
9 3
```

I am using this code in java but is not working, its only reading the first line can anyone help me?

```
    String []f; 
    String line;
    Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    while((line=in.nextLine())!=null){
        f=line.split(" ");

        int X,Y;
        X=Integer.parseInt(f[0]);
        Y=Integer.parseInt(f[1]);

        if(X<=40 && Y<=40)
          metohod(X,Y); 


        line=in.nextLine();

    }
}
```

Comment: As you proceed with acquiring and improving your java skills you should have look at the Java naming conventions. Here: field, member, variable names should always start with a lower-case letter, capitalized names represent classes (types).

Comment: `Scanner` != `BufferedReader`. `Scanner.nextLine()` never returns `null`. use `hasNextLine()` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling one `line=in.nextLine()` too much, but why not use `in.nextInt()`? The following should work as expectd:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

while(in.hasNextLine()) {
    int x = in.nextInt();
    int y = in.nextInt();

    if(x <= 40 && y <= 40)
        method(x, y); 
}
```

(The code is tested, and it reads more than just the first line. Your previous problem could perhaps be the new-line format of the input file.)

Have a look at the [scanner API docs](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

---

To debug this you could use the `Scanner(File file)` constructor instead.

Comment: I've also tried to use this code and it also only gave me de result for the first line of input. I don't know what is wrong :(

Comment: I suspect it has to do with how you feed the input to the program. Try instantiating the scanner using `in = new Scanner(new File("yourfile.txt"));` instead (for debugging).

Answer (score 1):

You are calling nextLine twice, once in the while, anotherone linha = xxx;
what is linha anyways?  Try this

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(...);
while((line = reader.readLine())!=null) {
  String[] f = line.split(" ");
  int X,Y;
  X=Integer.parseInt(f[0]);
  Y=Integer.parseInt(f[1]);
}
```

Comment: please add a printline to the line.  It is possible that you are using a unix file (with \n at the end) and reading it in windows (expecting \r\n).

Answer (score 0):

```
line=in.nextLine();
```

You are reading the next line and doing nothing with it. If you remove that it should work.

Comment: Sorry about this, it was a mistake when i was changing the code for you to understand better, i've change it already.

Comment: Yeah I thought so :). Anyways, if you remove that line you should be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using `Scanner`, why don't you just use `nextInt()` instead of `nextLine()`? That way you could call `nextInt()` twice and get the two numbers for each line.

The way you coded it looks as if you are trying to use a `BufferedReader` instead of a `Scanner`.